# JQuery function that works across forms created in formset

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery function that works as intended on an individual form within a formset to create a chained dropdown.

```
$("#id_form-0-state").change(function () {
    var stateId = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'subscriptions:relevantStates' %}",
        data: {
            'id': stateId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#id_form-0-counties").html(data);
        }
    });
})
```

It would be possible that there could be as many as 50 forms in the formset of the "#id_form-"+ i +"-state" and while I could copy/paste the function 50 times to account for all possibilities of i, there must be an easier way.

I'm new to JQuery so please forgive me if this is obvious.  I've looked for the solution to this for a couple of days but I cannot find anything in the docs or other questions about how to make this modify the "#id_form-"+ i +"-counties" as it is not a child of the "#id_form-"+ i +"-state" in the form.

Comment: Give them all the same class, and use a class selector instead of selecting the ID.

Comment: Give them a class would be best, if you can't you can use `[id^="id_form-"]`

Comment: I looked at giving them the same class, but I am not sure how I would get the information to the right "counties" because "id_form-0-state" would have different counties than "id_form-1-state" and the examples I saw on class based selection would apply to all of members of the class.

Comment: And I looked at using [id^='id_form-'] but that would trigger the function to run when the 'id_form-0-counties' changed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, I got it to work by using an "attribute ends with Selector" as explained [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).  Then I had to parse the triggered jQuery Object to get the original id to be able to rebuild the full id to populate the chained dropdown items with the returned ajax data.

```
$('select[id$="-state"]').change(function () {
    var stateId= this.value;
    var str = this.id;
    var foo = str.split("-");
    formId = foo[1];

    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'subscriptions:relevantCounties' %}",
        data: {
            'id': stateId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#id_form-"+ formId +"-counties").html(data);
        }
    });
})
```